# Windows mistakenly thinks cx_freeze frozen app has crashed when it has simply ended

Tags: python, windows, crash, cx-freeze

Got cx_freeze to work with Python 3.3.2 and 64-bit Windows 7. Wrote an application that runs flawlessly, but whenever it exits, Windows throws up a box saying that it has crashed and then another box that says that the program did not work correctly and that there is a compatbility problem.

The program exists gracefully with this code...

```
def ExitProgram():        
    LeaveSystemCallback()

def LeaveSystemCallback():
    #Windows SysExit Sound
    if Glvar.operating_system == "Windows":
        SysExit()
        root.destroy()
        sys.exit()
```

The details of the alleged crash are as follows:

Problem signature:

```
  Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH
  Application Name: EthicsAssessment.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    53826f33
  Fault Module Name:  python33.dll
  Fault Module Version: 3.3.2150.1013
  Fault Module Timestamp: 5194070a
  Exception Code:   c000041d
  Exception Offset: 0000000000188105
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 8056
  Additional Information 2: 80565c59c1732184e98f4355760f3681
  Additional Information 3: 6037
  Additional Information 4: 60378b49ba0e1a6f98bc5d7c54dfa3ea
```

I simply would like to get rid of that pesky error message so people don't think there's something wrong with the software upon termination.

Comment: What does `SysExit()` do?

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that Windows is mistaken about this.  There are a number of reasons why a process might crash while it is attempting to exit.  Typically something is being freed, unloaded, or closed while it is still in use.  The exception code you're getting is "An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback."  The first thing I would suggest you try is removing the calls to SysExit() and root.destroy().  Depending on your programming experience, running the application in a debugger might also give you useful clues.